# What is the name of the function that indexes Grothendieck universes?

Tags: set-theory, notation, terminology

Assume Tarski-Grothendieck set theory. Then Grothendieck universes form a well-ordered proper class, so we can let $U_\alpha$ denote the $\alpha$'th Grothendieck universe, where $\alpha$ is an ordinal.

Does the (proper class) function $\alpha \mapsto U_\alpha$ have a name?

Comment: I'd like to propose Grothendex [alternatively Grothindex].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a widespread name for this function, because otherwise someone would have answered it after 4.5 years.

Comment: I, goblin Obama, approve this message.

Comment: I just couldn't resist …

Comment: Let's face it, your reasoning is impeccable :)